# How can i get date format like MM/dd/yyyy using DateInput in react - admin

Tags: react-admin

```
const dateFormatter = v => {
    if (!(v instanceof Date) || isNaN(v)) return;
    const pad = '00';
    const yy = v.getFullYear().toString();
    const mm = (v.getMonth() + 1).toString();
    const dd = v.getDate().toString();
    return `${(pad + mm).slice(-2)}-${(pad + dd).slice(-2)}-${yy}`;
};
const dateParser = v => {
    const match = /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/.exec(v);
    if (match === null) return;
    const d = new Date(match[1], parseInt(match[2], 10) - 1, match[3]);
    if (isNaN(d)) return;
    return d;
};

<DateInput
    className="location-input" label="Purchase Date" source="PurchaseDate" 
    format={dateFormatter} parse={dateParser} validate={required()} 
/>
```

This format I'm using but not get like this MM/dd/yy but I only get dd/MM/yy please give some solution.

Comment: I recommend you to use `momentjs` or `dayjs` to format you date in the format and parse method to format you date. Much easier.

Comment: I don't need the current date & time I need to select datepicker format, sir.

Answer (score 0):

With `momentjs`, you can achieved this with

```
const dateParser = date => {
    if (!(date instanceof Date) || isNaN(date)) return;
    return moment(date).format('MM/DD/YY');
};
```

In Addition, react-admin DateInput comes from https://github.com/vascofg/react-admin-date-inputs, so following the doc, you should can do this

```
<DateInput options={{ format: 'MM/DD/YY' }} />
```